Why sending parallel pings in .NET is very slow?
I am trying to choose nodes to connect to by pinging about 100 of them in parallel, and picking top 5 with best latency. The problem is: it takes very long time to submit the pings.
I'm creating a new Ping instance for each host, and calling SendPingAsync(IPAddress) overload. Sending 16 pings (e.g. new Ping().SendPingAsync(addr), just getting tasks without awaiting) takes whopping 400ms. To submit the whole set takes >2s.
Initially I though it might be due to Ping constructor, but it takes about the same time even if I precreate the necessary number of Ping instances.
Is there a faster way to ping nodes?
P.S. Eventually I am accessing a TCP service on the nodes, so initially I was trying with TcpClient.ConnectAsync instead of Ping.SendPingAsync, and basically had the same problem: the last ConnectAsync (again, no awaiting, just getting the Task) would happen >2s after the first one.

Put your code here pls.

My code runs under 2 seconds with Ping results:

    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] lstHosts = ["149.28.36.241", "142.251.141.46", "20.76.201.171","205.251.242.103","86.124.128.163","20.119.8.53",
                                "20.231.239.246","31.13.84.36","3.165.206.87","13.107.42.14","17.253.144.10","104.18.32.7","104.16.107.144",
                                "130.211.198.204"];

            Stopwatch Watch = new Stopwatch();
            Watch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < lstHosts.Length; i++)        
                Test(lstHosts[i]).Wait();
            Watch.Stop();
    
            Console.WriteLine($"Time elapsed: {Watch.Elapsed}");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async Task Test(string host)
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(host);        
            Console.WriteLine($"ADDRESS - {host}:{ reply.Address.ToString()}");
            Console.WriteLine("TIME:" + reply.RoundtripTime);
        }
    }


This code is not parallel. 1 second it a lot to ping 10 hosts that reply under 100ms

@Lost - Exactly... I can ping the hosts under 2 seconds and not in a parallel mode, is just a prove that  ping.SendPingAsync works well and there is a problem in your code somewhere.... code that u didn't put to be investigated.

Turned out the issue was with Rider's debugger, that was slowing something down to a crawl. Outside of debugger all the pings were sent in under 100ms and replies received shortly.
